# calculate the occurence and store the result in a key value-pair using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to calculate the occurence of the name in an array.

```
var eachAuthorData = ["bob","joke","hello","stack","stack","ok","joke","bob"];
```

I can do this by using a for loop,and get a result like this

```
{bob: 2, joke: 2, hello: 1, stack: 2, ok: 1}
```

but the result can only be access using

```
counts["bob"]
```

not only do I need to know the occrence of each name.
but also need to know how many diffent name in the array eachAuthorData
how do I locate bob in the eachAuthorData
I only need to use the name once

Comment: What you have, is not an array.

Comment: What you want as a key and value ?? btw its not an array. for this you will get java script error.

Comment: Or even legal javascript.  @user3587729, please fix your code to be legal (either make it a legal object or legal array) and then clarify what you want the result to look like (ideally show us what you want the resulting object to actually look like).

Comment: @jfriend00 Oops, I was thinking about Python. Yup, not even valid JS.

Comment: yea,I made a mistake..Is there any way to address the problem?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with an array:

```
var eachAuthorData = ["bob","joke","hello","stack","stack","ok","joke","bob"];
```

and you want to know how many of each name there is in the array and how many unique strings there are, you can do it like this:

```
var counts = {}, i, item, uniques = 0;
for (i = 0; i < eachAuthorData.length; i++) {
    item = eachAuthorData[i];
    if (!counts.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        counts[item] = 1;
        ++uniques;
    } else {
        ++counts[item];
    }
}
```

This will generate an output in `counts` like this:

```
{bob: 2, joke: 2, hello: 1, stack: 2, ok: 1}
```

And, since you asked a few other questions in comments, I added the variable `uniques` which gives you the total unique string count.

And, you would access any individual count like this:

```
var cnt = counts["bob"];
```

Or, if the desired key is in a variable named `key`, you would use:

```
var cnt = counts[key];
```

---

If you want to iterate all the counts of all the unique strings, you can do that like this:

```
for (var item in counts) {
    // item is the key
    // counts[item] is the count
    console.log("counts[" + item + "] = " + counts[item]);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eJyAg/

---

If you want a list of the keys in the counts object (e.g. the unique strings), you can use:

```
var keys = Object.keys(counts);
```

`Object.keys()` requires IE9 or greater or there's a polyfill [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) if you want interoperability with older versions of IE.

Comment: +1 because it's almost identical to what I wrote (but took about 10 seconds longer to prepare to post!).

Comment: finaly,my problem is here,I can't use counter["bob"],the array is generated by program and i don't know whats in it,i want to use counter[1] instead.That's why I want to put it into a key-value pair

Comment: @user3587729 - please explain what problem you're trying to solve then.  You access properties of an object with the `obj[propName]` syntax.  `propName` can be a string or a variable.

Comment: @user3587729 - see more I added to the end of my answer and the working demo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have:

```
var eachAuthorData = ["bob","joke","hello","stack","stack","ok","joke","bob"];
```

do this to count:

```
var toMatch, i, count;

toMatch = "bob";
count   = 0;

for( i=0 ; i<eachAuthorData.length ; ++i ){
  if( eachAuthorData[i] == toMatch ){
    ++count;
  }
}

console.log("The element "+ toMatch +" is counted "+ count +" times!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var tempObject = new Object();
function count() {
    array_elements = ["bob","joke","hello","stack","stack","ok","joke","bob"];

    array_elements.sort();

    var current = null;
    var cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++) {
        if (array_elements[i] != current) {
            if (cnt > 0) {
                tempObject[current]=cnt;
                console.log(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times<br>');
            }
            current = array_elements[i];
            cnt = 1;
        } else {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    if (cnt > 0) {
        console.log(current + ' comes --> ' + cnt + ' times');
       tempObject[current]=cnt;
    }

}

count();
console.log(JSON.stringify(tempObject));
```

Answer (score -2):

Presumably you meant an array like:

```
var data = ["bob","joke","hello","stack","stack","ok","joke","bob"];
```

Since others have gone the obvious route, I'll post something a little more robust that accounts for the possibility that the data array has elided members (i.e. is sparse):

```
function countMembers(dataArray) {

  for (var i=0, iLen=dataArray.length, o={}, item; i<iLen; i++) {
    item = dataArray[i];

    if (dataArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       if (o.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
          ++o[item];
       } else {
          o[item] = 1;
       }
    } 
  }
  return o;
}
```

Given:

```
["bob","joke",,,,"hello","stack","stack","ok","joke","bob"];
```

others will include a member `undefined: 3`, but the above wont.

Comment: That's basically a repeat of jfriend00's answer, just with different variables...